# Как создать некоторое количество TextBox-ов?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть поле ввода. После ввода значения `N = 2, ..., 5` должно появится N `textbox`-ов.  Как это сделать?

Comment: Уже реализовал это, новый вопрос, может быть вы знаете ответ на него, нужно в ComboBox, внести массив символов как это сделать?

Comment: Если вы знаете ответ на свой вопрос, то напишите его сюда, он нам пригодится. Если у вас второй вопрос, то задавайте его отдельно

Comment: Можете помочь со следующим вопросом? Я могу линк на него кинуть

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение из комментария @roxyash:

```
int count = int.Parse(Count_TextBox.Text);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{    
    TextBox textBox = new TextBox
        {
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
            Height = 15,
            Width = 50,
            Margin = new Thickness((i + 1) * 100, 50, 0, 0),
        };
        Main.Children.Add(textBox);
  }
```